# Insert related model

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.
Как в laravel можно занести значения в базу приходящие массивом на связи `hasMany`? Аналог `attach` на belongsToMany связи.

```
$person = Person::create($request->all());
$person->fields->createmany($request->fields); // выходит ошибка
```

`$request->fields` - это масстив. Все выглядит так

```
array(
    'first_name' => 'Test'
    'fields' => array(
        0 => 'asdasd',
        1 => 'asda312312sd',
        2 => 'a123123sdasd',
    )
)
```

Знаю про `saveMany` но он тоже выдает ошибки

Comment: а sync  и attach принимают же массив

Comment: да. Они принимают массив на связи `belongsToMany`, но на связи `hasMany` их нет. А то что есть, это - `create / save / saveMany / createMany`. Но с ними не выходило.Проблему решил еще вчера.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3251, почитай что пишет Тео Отвел насчет этого

Answer (score 0):

Решил так

```
/**
 * Attach related model
 *
 * @param array $aGroup
 * @return AttributeGroup|array
 */
public function attachRelated(Array $aGroup)
{
    $instances = [];

    foreach($aGroup as $group)
    {
        $instances[] = new AttributeGroup(['name' => $group]);
    }

    return $instances;
}
```

И теперь делаем так

```
$person = Person::create($request->all());

if($request->fields) // если заполнены данные в поле fields[]
    {
        $person->fields()->saveMany($this->attachRelated($request->fields));
    }
```